# SimpleDoubleProperty.set(double) throwing NPE

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have a small financial application that is showing a market data watch list (current bid price/current ask price) in a TableView.

The bid/ask prices are being updated in real time for each of the symbols that I'm watching.

Everything works exceptionally well, but occasionally I get a NullPointerException when trying to set either the bid or sometimes the ask price.

Here's a snippet from my GUI Controller that sets up the TableView and Columns

```
TableColumn<PositionRowData, Number> bidColumn = new TableColumn<PositionRowData, Number>(BID_COLUMN_NAME);
TableColumn<PositionRowData, Number> askColumn = new TableColumn<PositionRowData, Number>(ASK_COLUMN_NAME);
TableColumn<PositionRowData, Number> lastColumn = new TableColumn<PositionRowData,Number>(LAST_COLUMN_NAME);
.
.
.
   //and later on the column is initialized like this
bidColumn.setCellFactory(new USDTableCellRenderer());
bidColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<PositionRowData,Number>, ObservableValue<Number>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<Number> call(
                CellDataFeatures<PositionRowData, Number> arg0) {
            return arg0.getValue().getBid();
        }
   });

//finally the columns are added to the table
TableView.getColumns().addAll(....bidColumn..etc);
```

Here's a snippet from my PositionRowData constructor with initialization:

```
bid = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
ask = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
```

Here's what my setter code looks like:

```
public void setBid(double bid) {
    try {
        this.bid.set(bid);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        _log.error("Would have been NPE in setBid. trying to set new value: "+bid);
    }
}
```

- Btw - It's not my usual habit to catch my NPEs! I just stuck that in there because I wanted a more graceful error for the person who was testing this for me!

Here's the full stack trace:

```
2013-06-20 11:56:12,500 ERROR [DataChannel Reader Thread] - NPE
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.beans.property.DoublePropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.beans.property.DoublePropertyBase.markInvalid(Unknown Source)
at javafx.beans.property.DoublePropertyBase.set(Unknown Source)
at com.eak070.ui.tablemodel.PositionRowData.setAsk(PositionRowData.java:86)
at com.eak070.ui.ETGUIController.onQuote(ETGUIController.java:808)
at com.eak070.ui.ETGUIController$24.handleDataChannelMessage(ETGUIController.java:737)
at com.eak070.communication.stream.DataChannel.processDataChannelMessage(DataChannel.java:211)
at com.eak070.communication.stream.DataChannel.readFromSocketChannel(DataChannel.java:156)
at com.eak070.communication.stream.DataChannel.access$1(DataChannel.java:122)
at com.eak070.communication.stream.DataChannel$1.run(DataChannel.java:99)
```

I'm not quite sure what's going on as I'm still somewhat new to JavaFX and don't really know the ins and outs of bindings.

This appears to be happening sporadically. In other words I can't yet reproduce it on purpose. It just happens seemingly randomly.

This feels like it might be a threading issue, but I'm just not sure why there's a NPE inside of the set() method since rows in this table aren't being destroyed. Once rows are created they hang around forever. Any advice/thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Is this setter running in the GUI event thread or another thread?

Comment: Please show us the stack trace

Comment: @PeterLawrey - the setter is running in another thread.

Comment: @tieTYT - Working on getting that trace now. Will update the issue as soon as I dig it up.

Comment: @eak0703 If you update something in one thread which is accessed in another you can get random failures.  I suggest only calling this method using the GUI e.g. SwingUtils.invokeLater() (There is a JavaFX equivelent but I forget what it is)

Comment: @tieTYT - just added the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

When I see your code snippet... you use

```
new SimpleDoubleProperty()
```

and you never set the bean and the name of property to set. I guess it really invokes NullPointerException, but not because of value (Double -> double casting), but because you haven't set the bean or property name.

Comment: The odd thing is that the code executes thousands of times and is fine.  Maybe once in several weeks this NPE happens though.

Comment: Have you checked your class DataChannel as it shows the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's still relevant, but I've just encountered the same thing in my app and the answer was as peter lawrey said - call the set method only on the event thread with Platform.runLater()